# My Boyfriend and I's favorite song... How would you phrase this?

Tags: descriptive-grammar

I was always taught that if you want to make sure that the possessive pronouns are correct when referring to more than one person, you should try to say the sentence alone and use that pronoun. My boyfriend's favorite song is... Sounds good right? I favorite song...not so good.  So I would suggest stating the sentence like this. My Boyfriend's and my favorite song is... Still sounds a bit clunky, but I believe this is grammatically correct. What do you think?

Comment: Also see *[How do you make the possessive form with “He and I”-style subjects?](/questions/38847)* and *[What possessive forms are used for mutual 1st person ownership?](/questions/8520)*

Comment: The thing is that _I_ is a pronoun, and pronouns don't just take a possessive apostrophe-_S_, so there is no good solution, unless you prefer _my_ instead of _I's_. One thing people do is say _the favorite song of me and my boyfriend_.

Comment: I would recommend "my boyfriend's and my favorite song" or "my and my boyfriend's favorite song".

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the other 2 cited. This is because of what it *means* rather than grammar. The above seafood dinner is a single object credited to two people. By contrast, if a song is my favourite, it is so because of how much *I* like it relative to other songs; nobody else is involved in my choosing to designate that song as my favourite. So if my boyfriend's favourite song is the same as my favourite, that is a coincidence of two separate facts, which are expressed by separate uses of possessive forms as @tautophile showed.